How to select multiple cells in VBA if there is a blank in between?
If I can dynamically (without hardcoded cell range) come to the yellow marked cell "", how can I select the range like in the screenshot dynamically? xlDown brings me only to the row before the blank..
I am stuggling to find a simple solution to that.


Look for the last row in the column maybe?

You can’t use xlDown +1?

@cybernetic.nomad That's an oldtimer. Surely you must have noticed the issues in the accepted (heavily upvoted) answer e.g. the parameters declared as Variant, unqualified references, the LookIn parameter omitted,... You can link to specific answers, e.g. GSerge's answer.

it's not the last row in that column. There are other table below that cell in that column AA. But I want to select data from the Cell whivch contains "FC Mai 2024" to the cell which contains 62 in that column.

Reference the Single-Column Range From a Given Cell to the Last Non-Empty Cell in the Column Using the Range.End Property

Range.End Property (Docs)

There are many ways to do it but the simplest, usually learned first, is to use the Range.End property.

All the ways have issues, so does this:

The reference to the range will be wrong in the following cases:

if the given cell and all the cells below (AA6:AA1048576) are empty (likely),
if the last cell (AA1048576) in the column is not empty (rarely (never!?)).




Note that only the 3rd solution that uses a function deals with these issues.

Test the issues by using the procedures in a new workbook gradually adding values to the AA column starting from the top.

If you have blank cells that are not empty at the bottom of the column, you cannot discard them using this way. One way of doing this would be to use the Range.Find method with (most importantly) its 3rd parameter LookIn set to xlValues with its list of issues.

Get familiar with the many ways by studying Siddharth Rout's legendary answer to the question "Find last used cell in Excel VBA".


Hard-Coded (Basic)
Sub TestEndHardCoded()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = ws.Range("AA6", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp))
    
    MsgBox "The referenced range is """ & rg.Address(0, 0) _
        & """ on worksheet """ & ws.Name & """.", vbInformation
        
End Sub

Dynamic (Simple)
Sub TestEndDynamic()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim fcell As Range: Set fcell = ws.Range("AA6")
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(fcell, _
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, fcell.Column).End(xlUp))
    
    MsgBox "The referenced range is """ & rg.Address(0, 0) _
        & """ on worksheet """ & ws.Name & """.", vbInformation
        
End Sub

Dynamic (Using a Helper Function)
Sub TestEndFunction()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim fcell As Range: Set fcell = ws.Range("AA6")
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = RefSingleColumnRangeEnd(fcell, True)
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    MsgBox "The referenced range is """ & rg.Address(0, 0) _
        & """ on worksheet """ & ws.Name & """.", vbInformation
        
End Sub

Function RefSingleColumnRangeEnd( _
    ByVal firstCell As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ShowFailMessage As Boolean = False) _
As Range
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = _
        "Reference Single-Column Range Using the End Property"
    
    With firstCell.Cells(1)
        
        Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = .Worksheet
        Dim wrCount As Long: wrCount = ws.Rows.Count
        
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(wrCount, .Column)) Then
            Set RefSingleColumnRangeEnd = .Resize(wrCount - .Row + 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
            
        Dim RowsCount As Long:
        RowsCount = ws.Cells(wrCount, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        
        If RowsCount < 1 Then
            If ShowFailMessage Then
                MsgBox "No data found in range """ _
                    & .Resize(wrCount - .Row + 1).Address(0, 0) _
                    & """ on worksheet """ & ws.Name & """!", _
                    vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
        
        Set RefSingleColumnRangeEnd = .Resize(RowsCount)
    
    End With

End Function


This method returns the range in column "I" as a Range object.
Sub used()

Set col = Columns("I")   'or
'Set col = ActiveCell.Column 'dynamical
first = col.Cells(1).End(xlDown).Address
last = col.Cells(rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address
Set usedrng = Range(first & ":" & last)

End Sub


This will return wrong range when there is data in the first or the last cell of I, or when I is entirely empty. It opts to use Range(string) instead of the Range(r1, r2) too.

@Gserg exactly. Therefore give the answer for the attached example.

Since the OP question was I am stuggling to find a simple solution to that. , this answer fulfil the request perfectly.
